# Add space before uppercase letter

Tags: linux, command-line, text-formatting

I have a strings:

```
AddData
TestSomething
TellMeWhoYouAre
```

and so on. I want to add space before uppercase letters. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want to do when there are consecutive upper case letters? example `IClimbALadder`

Comment: Actually I have a strings like `ReadFileFromCDDrive` and @Kusalananda 's solution works great.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `sed`, and assuming you don't want a space in front of the word:

```
$ sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]\)\([[:upper:]]\)/\1 \2/g' file.in
Add Data
Test Something
Tell Me Who You Are
```

The substitution will look for an upper-case letter immediately following a another non-whitespace character, and insert a space in-between the two.

For strings with more than one consecutive upper-case character, like `WeAreATeam`, this produces `We Are ATeam`. To sort this, run the substitution a second time:

```
$ sed -e 's/\([^[:blank:]]\)\([[:upper:]]\)/\1 \2/g' \
      -e 's/\([^[:blank:]]\)\([[:upper:]]\)/\1 \2/g' file.in
```

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks for your answer. I've tried your solution with my case and it works well except the only one problem when I've tried it with `ReadFileFromUSBDrive`

Comment: @HeroFromEarth What would you want that string to be turned into? `Read File From U S B Drive` or `Read File From USBDrive`?

Comment: @Kusalananda I want to turn it to `Read File From USB Drive`

Comment: Shorter line if you don't have a space at the start (are using camelCase): `sed 's|\([[:upper:]]\)| &|g'`

Answer (score 13):

Perl, using lookbehind and lookahead zero-width regular expressions:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=\w)(?=[A-Z])/ /g'  file.in 

Tell Me Who You Are                    ## TellMeWhoYouAre
I Am A Regular Expression User         ## IAmARegulaExpressionUser
```

This version is also separating consecutive uppercase letters.

Comment: This turns `ReadFileFromUSBDrive` into `Read File From U S B Drive` whereas the OP wanted `Read File From USB Drive`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thank you for pointing it out. (I'm afraid I dont see that written in the question). In real situations (programming understanding, id words expanding, and CamelCase variants) it is common to use a basic criteria (either split in single Uppercase or the opposite) and have a dictionary of exceptions.

Comment: Sorry, it was something the OP wrote in the comments to my answer. I agree, it's difficult to do this without a word list of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r -e "s/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g"
```

Add space between a letter that is not an upper-case letter and a letter that is an upper-case letter

Answer (score 2):

Came here to get this question answered and, after reading the other suggestions, arrived at a solution that handles the `ReadFromUSBDrive` to `Read From USB Drive` case, too - I adapted [ka3ak's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/163956/ka3ak) expression style and [kusalananda's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) use of multiple expressions to get the following:

```
 sed -r -e "s/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g" -e "s/([A-Z]+)([A-Z])/\1 \2/g" file.in
```

e.g.

```
$ sed -r -e "s/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/\1 \2/g" -e "s/([A-Z]+)([A-Z])/\1 \2/g" <<EOF
AddData
TestSomething
TellMeWhoYouAre
ReadFromUSBDrive
EOF
Add Data
Test Something
Tell Me Who You Are
Read From USB Drive
```

Note that this will choke on single-letter words like the article "A" or the pronoun "I" when they occur directly before an abbreviation as they would be indistinguishable from the characters in an intended abbreviation, e.g. `ReadAUSBDrive` will render `Read AUSB Drive`.

Answer (score 0):

Python solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        for char in line:
            if char.isupper():
               print(" "+char,end="")
            else:
               print(char,end="")
```

Test run:

```
$ ./add_space_to_upper.py input.txt                        
 Add Data
 Test Something
 Tell Me Who You Are
```

Comment: You want `print(line[0], end="")` followed by `for char in line[1:]:` to avoid printing that unwanted space at the beginning of every output line.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

Sample Input:

```
AddData
TestSomething
TellMeWhoYouAre
IClimbALadder
ReadFileFromCDDrive
ReadAUSBDrive
```

Code and Output (1):

```
raku -pe 's:g/(<?after <:Ll> >) (<?before <:Lu>+ >)/ /;' 

Add Data
Test Something
Tell Me Who You Are
IClimb ALadder
Read File From CDDrive
Read AUSBDrive
```

Code and Output (2):

```
raku -pe 's:g/(<?after <:L> >) (<?before <:Lu>+ >)/ /;' 

Add Data
Test Something
Tell Me Who You Are
I Climb A Ladder
Read File From C D Drive
Read A U S B Drive
```

Above is a pretty direct translation of @JJoao's Perl5 code. The `<:L>`, `<:Ll>`, and `<:Lu>` represent "Unicode letter", "Unicode letter-lower", and `Unicode letter-upper", respectively.

Addendum: Like others in this thread have noted, it appears that sequential `s///` substitution calls can get you closer to a desired output. Below, take the results of the first Raku example (above), and run a second `s///` substitution:

Code and Output (3):

```
raku -pe 's:g/(<?after <:Ll> >) (<?before <:Lu> >)/ /;'  | perl6 -pe 's:g/(<?after <:Lu>+ >) (<?before <:Lu><:Ll>+ >)/ /;'

Add Data
Test Something
Tell Me Who You Are
I Climb A Ladder
Read File From CD Drive
Read AUSB Drive
```

The results with Raku (5/6 test lines separated correctly), equals the best results obtained with other languages posted thus far.

http://raku.org